# In Django how do I set a certain requests session using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, django

I am trying to implement a shopping-cart and hence require to set my requests session using angularjs. For example if I have a number of products and once the user clicks on a certain products 'Add To Cart' button I want to add that product in the session's cart object. The main objective of opting for sessions is that I want this cart to be accessible on the other requested view. Is there any possible solution?

Lets consider I have a view named products_list:-

```
def products_list(request):
    // Somehow set session using Angularjs like below
    // request.session['cart'] = selected_products_list
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "browse_products.html", {'products': products})
```

So that I can access those selected products in an another view like this:-

```
 def checkout(request):
     selected_products = request.session['cart']
     return render(request, "checkout.html", {'selected_products': selected_products})
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. The way to set a session variable, whether you're using angular or not, will be the same, using code similar to what you have commented out. You can use Angular to send an Ajax request to a view that does that.

Comment: A separate view to handle sessions and then there i can do AJAX requests right?

Comment: I get what you are saying. Can You post an answer so that I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update sessions dynamically I created an another view as suggested by @Daniel Roseman.

```
def update_cart_session(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart = json.loads(request.body)
        request.session['cart'] = cart["cart"]
        print request.session['cart']
        return HttpResponse('OK')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not a POST Method")
```

And to send cart items using AngularJS I used the HTTP post method:-

```
var url = "your_url_pointing_to_above_view";
var data= {
    "cart": $scope.cart
};
$http.post(url, data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);         
function successCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
};
function errorCallback(error){
    console.log(error);
    swal("Oops!", "Check your internet connection!", "error");          
};
```